# Perl: iterating values in for loop

Tags: perl

```
print "Input value \n";
$line = <>;
chomp $line;
@val = $line;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
  print -@val* $i;
}
```

I have a simple for loop here where the user enters a value that I store into the `@val`, and I want my loop to iterate from 1 to 10 and print out the value of `-@val * $i`. Suppose my `@val = 2`, then I should see the output: -2 -4 -6 - 8 ... -20. But my actual output is: -1 -2 ... -10. What went wrong?

Comment: I'm new to perl so I don't know why actually. How can I store it as just an integer?

Comment: It's difficult to help you as I don't understand why you're copying the value in `$line` to an array. Can you explain your thinking there please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, I can't imagine what you were trying to achieve by copying the value of `$line` to array `@val`. There are also a number of other points that I would like to make

- You must always

  ```
  use strict;
  use warnings 'all';
  ```

  at the start of all your Perl programs. You will then have to declare all of your variables with `my`, and it will alert you to many simple errors that you may otherwise overlook
- The C-style `for` loop is rarely useful in Perl. It is usually best to iterate over a simple list. In your program that would be

  ```
  for my $i ( 1 .. 10 ) {
      ...
  }
  ```

So putting all that together, your program looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

print "Input value\n";
my $val = <>;
chomp $val;

for my $i ( 1 .. 10 ) {
  print -$val * $i;
}
```

It's also worth pointing out that, when the contents of the `for` loop is just a single statement like this, you can use `for` as a statement modifier and write just

```
print -$val * $_ for 1 .. 10;
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're storing your value in an array (`@val`). When you use that array in a scalar context (the math in the for loop) you just get the number of elements in the array. In your case 1. Change `@val` to `$val` or just use `$line` directly.

Comment: `@val` is *not* a list -- it's an array. You may think that's a pedantic point, but in fact it's crucial to a proper understanding of Perl. Take a look at [***What is the difference between a list and an array?***](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array%3f) in `perlfaq4`

Comment: @Borodin I've updated the post. For the purposes of this question the distinction isn't that important as the OP didn't know the difference between a scalar and non-scalar.

Comment: On the contrary, the distinction is *always critical*. Especially for new learners, it's vital to tell the same story all the time